# PreferenceBundle: "number in code"

Tags: ios, bundle, jailbreak, tweak

I'm searching some help for an item in the PreferenceBundle.

For example, I have this simple code:

```
-(int)XXX {
    return 100;
}
```

How can I put in the PreferenceBundle a cell where you can write the number to return the function?

For example:
1) You write 5 and the function will be:

```
-(int)XXX {
    return 5;
}
```

2) you write 24:

```
-(int)XXX {
    return 24;
}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Using a PSEditTextCell and the data found in [the wiki page](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Preferences_specifier_plist#Editing_cells) you can add this specifier to your preferences pane. You can use NSUserDefaults and the notification posted from the cell being edited (you have to specify that) to retrieve the value the user has set and return it in your method.

You can use the code [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/User:Uroboro#How_2_prefs) to see how to setup and read the user preferences for your tweak.